# Why isn't the line with the else command in C language in the following code not being read?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{ 
int a,b,c;
printf("\n Enter any three numbers");
scanf("%d%d%d", &a,&b,&c);

if(a > b){
  if(a > c){
    printf("\n The greatest number is =%d",a);
  }
} else
    if(b > a) {
      if(b > c) { 
        printf("\n The greatest number is =%d",b);
      }
    } else {
      printf("\nThe greatest number=%d",c);
    }
getch();
}
```

When the third number is greatest, there is no output on the screen. I tried using F7 and got to know that the line with 'else' statement is being skipped. What to do since I need to use nested if only.

Comment: Having code in the same line after `{` is pretty awful and not very readable. Please don't do that. Also, fix the indentation of the rest of the code - often this is enough to spot issues related to control structures.

Comment: Fix your indentation to make the flow of control non-obfuscated.

Comment: The last `else` will only be reached if both `a>b` and `b>a` are false (i.e. only if `a==b`).

Comment: @Michael that's what I thought, but the code appears to be deliberately obfuscated to hide that fact, almost like a homework problem.

Comment: I fixed the indentation part in the original code and have tried entering numbers like 2,3,5. But still there is no output.

Comment: Please unlearn `void main` because in C it is `int main` and never #include conio.h again (use stdio.h and getchar() instead). This way you will learn to program C, as opposed to a language Bill Gates has mutilated :-)

Comment: Try _ending_ all the `printf`s with `\n`, not starting them

Comment: BTW, remove `if(b>a) 
{`

Comment: What importance does "using F7" have here?

Comment: I think that F7 reads the code line by line and goes on displaying appropriate output.

Comment: Actually I've just started learning programming. I'm learning C. My teacher uses Turbo C and always the conio.h header file. What all things like using int main instead of void main can be learnt and from where? @CoolGuy and Jens

Comment: @knight There are several tutorials about C on the web that teaches how to write good C code. Your code is OK if you are forced to use the ancient 25+ year old TurboC. Seriously, I recommend to ditch TurboC and install a modern compiler and IDE, say, GCC(compiler) and Code::Blocks(IDE).

Comment: It seems perfectly obvious that the OP wanted to know how to fix his logic, i.e., what is wrong with it. Appropriate comments were given. Hence the putting on hold seems rather mean spirited, not helpful. Even the world class expert was once a humble beginner. That humility should not be lost in the ascent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing abnormal here: your else statement corresponds to the case a==b ;)

Answer (score 0):

Minus other advice already given:

```
        if ((a > b) && (a > c)) {
            printf("\n The greatest number is =%d",a);
        }
        else {
            if ((b > a) && (b > c)) {
                printf("\n The greatest number is =%d",b);
            }
            else {
                printf("\nThe greatest number=%d",c);
            }
        }
```

C is one of those languages designed to minimize the keystrokes needed to express something, as though that were some kind of efficiency. However it causes the language to be relatively difficult to understand if the reader is not already familiar with the algorithm expressed. Thus the importance of proper and consistent formatting, which eliminates a level of analysis otherwise required.

(Actually, the human mind welcomes some redundancy in written expressions so it can verify its projections of meaning as it reads along. A few more keystrokes, as in Pascal for instance, enables the unfamiliar reader to more quickly comprehend the coder's intent.)